# How to remove an element from :class [Ljava.lang.String?

Tags: java, collections, groovy

I have this groovy code where I want to remove the very first element but I don't know how. `.drop(0)` doesn't do anything and  `.remove(0)` gives me an error : `groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.remove() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.Integer) values: [0] Possible solutions: reverse(), getAt(java.lang.Integer), reverse(boolean), drop(int), take(int) at Cert_RouteJob_exec_script_RouteJob.run(Cert_RouteJob_exec_script_RouteJob:16)`

**Could someone help me how to remove the first element and explain?**

```
        println job."Cert_Applications".getMetaClass()
        // result: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.HandleMetaClass@50446a34[groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl@50446a34[class [Ljava.lang.String;]]
        println job."Cert_Applications".getProperties()
        // result: [class:class [Ljava.lang.String;, length:16]

        println job."Cert_Applications".inspect()
        // result: ['Accept', 'Afp', 'Exe', 'IA', 'Exe', 'IA', 'IA', 'Afp', 'Afp', 'Exe', 'IA', 'Exe', 'Exe', 'Afp', 'IA', 'Afp']
        println job."Cert_Applications".toString()
        // result: [Accept, Afp, Exe, IA, Exe, IA, IA, Afp, Afp, Exe, IA, Exe, Exe, Afp, IA, Afp]

        applications = job."Cert_Applications"

        println applications.size()
        // result: 16

        if (applications.size() > 0){

        println applications[0]
        // result: Accept
        // applications.remove(0)
        println applications.drop(0)
        // result: [Accept, Afp, Exe, IA, Exe, IA, IA, Afp, Afp, Exe, IA, Exe, Exe, Afp, IA, Afp]

        }

        println applications.inspect()
        // result: ['Accept', 'Afp', 'Exe', 'IA', 'Exe', 'IA', 'IA', 'Afp', 'Afp', 'Exe', 'IA', 'Exe', 'Exe', 'Afp', 'IA', 'Afp']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `applications` is an array.  Arrays are statically sized.  You can't remove an element and have the array shrink to account for having removed that element.  You can do that with a `List`, but not with an array.

If you just want to null out the value at index zero you could do something like `applications[0] = null`.

**EDIT**

You could go through some gyrations like converting the array to a `List`, then remove the first element, then convert that back to an array if you like.  That could look something like this...

```
// this will fail if applications has fewer than 2 elements.
// size checking omitted here for brevity
applications = (applications as List)[1..-1] as String[]
```

Make sure you understand what is going on there before using that.  That may or may not be what you want to do.

If you really don't need the thing to be an array, you can simplify things by converting it to a `List` and then just carrying on.  Instead of this...

```
applications = job."Cert_Applications"
```

You could do this...

```
applications = job."Cert_Applications" as List
```

Then you could do something like `applications.remove(0)` to remove the first element from the `List`

Comment: Could you explain why there must at least two elements in the array for the removing through List to work?

Comment: It looks like I don't need it to be an array! :-) So you might have solved it. I need more testing...

Comment: There doesn't need to be at least two elements in the array to remove one.  There needs to be at least two for the `[1..-1]` syntax to work because that says something like "return the second element (that is at index 1) and every element from there until the last element (the element at index -1)".  If there are less than 2, there would be no second element so that syntax would throw an exception.